# Laravel 5 - how to get a random row from first 30 records in eloquent?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get a random row from the top 30 records in a table. I sort all the records by `score` first, and take 30 records in a scope of the eloquent model:

```
public function scopePopular($query, $d)
{
    return $query->where('d', $d)->orderBy('score', 'desc')->take(30);
}
```

Then in a `class`:

```
$cnt = Record::popular($d)->count();
if ($cnt == 0)
    return;

$randIndex = rand(0, $cnt-1);
$record = Record::popular($d)->skip($randIndex)->take(1)->first();
return $record;
```

But when I check in php artisan tinker, I found that `Record::popular($d)->count();` will return all the records number instead of 30. How can I correct this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get()` before `count()` to run the query before count:

```
$cnt = Record::popular($d)->get()->count();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are running the query 2 times. That is not necessary.

```
$cnt = Record::popular($d)->count(); // First query
if ($cnt == 0)
    return;

$randIndex = rand(0, $cnt-1);
$record = Record::popular($d)->skip($randIndex)->take(1)->first(); // Second query
return $record;
```

Instead you can do it like this:

```
return Record::popular($d)->get()->random(); // One query only
```

Comment: I tried this one before. And it always gives me the topmost record, instead of a random one in 30 records.

Comment: OK, yes I see it now, since the first order by is on score, it will always be the first order.. However you dont have to do 2 queries. You should really try to fetch the result one time and then select the random row from the result by php

Comment: Thanks. But the return value is changed. I need to return an eloquent model.

Comment: OK, see my updated answer. There is a `random()` function on collections in Laravel 5.1 and above

Comment: Thanks @henrik ! I will try it out.